# Is it possible to run a command when the user closes the cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt

I have a program that alters some important files on my PC. It deletes and rewrites program files. Is there a way to run a command after the user closes the command window? This way, if the program was in the midst of deleting and creating some files, it either finishes up or it reverts all files back to normal. I saw other questions like this but I didn't understand some of the answers. Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Check out the `atexit` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: @DanielWalker I thought atexit only works when the code finishes on its own. Does it also work when the program is closed by the user?

Comment: Hm, good point.  Depending on how the user killed the program, perhaps a signal handler would work.